# Можно ли более эффективно сравнить блоки памяти?

Tags: c#, память, unsafe

Я написал простой компаратор указателей памяти, и интересует вопрос, можно ли в случае именно си шарпа, написать более эффективный, или может быть уже где-то есть компараторы памяти о которых я не знаю?

```
private static bool IsAvi(char[] buffer)
{
    char[] riff = new[] { 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F' };
    char[] avi  = new[] { 'A', 'V', 'I', ' ' };
    char[] on2  = new[] { 'O', 'N', '2', ' ' };
    char[] on2f = new[] { 'O', 'N', '2', 'f' };

    int index = 0;

    fixed(char* riffPtr = riff, aviPtr = avi, on2Ptr = on2, on2fPtr = on2f, bufferPtr = buffer)
    {
        char* peek = bufferPtr;

        for (index = 0; index < 188; index++)
        {
            if(MemoryCompare(&peek[0], riffPtr, 4) && MemoryCompare(&peek[8], aviPtr, 4))
            {
                break;
            }

            if(MemoryCompare(&peek[0], on2Ptr, 4) && MemoryCompare(&peek[8], on2fPtr, 4))
            {
                break;
            }

            peek++;
        }

        return index != 188;
    }
}

private static bool MemoryCompare(void* first, void* second, uint count)
{
    byte* firstPtr = (byte*)first;
    byte* secondPtr = (byte*)second;

    for (uint i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(firstPtr[i]  != secondPtr[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ну может Span с их SequenceEqual. А вообще посмотрите реализацию [MemoryExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/MemoryExtensions.cs) метод SequenceCompareTo, который ссылается на SpanHelpers.SequenceCompareTo, реализации которого там рядом лежат. Также [сюда](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/22763) можно глянуть

Comment: Побайтово сравнивать явно неэффективно. Нужно сравнивать long'и (на 64-битной машине), а оставшийся хвост (1-7 байт) побайтно.

Comment: Не уверен, можно ли прикрутить Vector [struct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=netstandard-2.1) или [class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector?view=netstandard-2.1).

Comment: Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808245/. В вашем случае - всегда 4 байта - можно сократить код до сравнения int, без цикла в Compare.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43289/5045688 - Я бы нативную `memcmp` попробовал.

Comment: Раз уж вы работаете с низкоуровневым кодом, то дам полезную (надеюсь) ссылку: [Buffer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer?view=netframework-4.8). Методов сравнения этот класс не имеет, но есть методы копирования (быстрые).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, про [`Buffer`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYcPa.png), знаю, а вот `memcmp` попробую.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, кстати, `Vector` есть на [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors/). Но ради сравнения блоков тащить всю библиотеку, пока не представляю желания.